# Facebook Share Dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am building a Facebook app and trying to implement a share dialog. Currently, I've only found how to create a feed dialog that allows you to post to your own wall (see image below).

[current app post dialog http://perian.atlantafalcons.com/falcons_post.png](http://perian.atlantafalcons.com/falcons_post.png)

What I am trying to achieve is a "Share" dialog that allows users to select whether they want to post to their own wall, on a friend's timeline, or a page. Spotify allows this functionality from their feed posts (see spotify example image below).

[spotify share dialog http://perian.atlantafalcons.com/spotify_share.png](http://perian.atlantafalcons.com/spotify_share.png)

In addition to creating the share dialog, how do I add a "Share" action next to "Like" and "Comment" on a feed post?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: App is here if anyone is looking for context: http://www.facebook.com/atlantafalcons/app_292392080815275

Comment: FYI, bug (request) filed here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/327210807373833

Comment: Thanks!!! Subscribed. Hopefully it gets fixed/added soon.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is the [Share Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/).  Facebook has deprecated this and claim it will no longer be supported.  If you want, you can still directly pop open a window with the content of the sharer by using a url similar to this:

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://google.com

and just change out the value of the `u` query string parameter

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Problem I guess I have is that I'm not sharing link. My app is posting a video and it links directly back to the app. Guess there's no way of doing this with the same functionality of the "share button"?